# Error when receiving email in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've set up a forward mailbox in Dynamics CRM 2013 using the new server profile features and I an alert when performing the test and enable action. The error I am receiving is `"The location of the mailbox [name] could not be determined while receiving email.`".

The server profile is connected to an Office 365 and appears to be working fine for a user mailbox.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be with Office 365's auto discover.

Setting the Email Server Profiles incoming and outgoing address to https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx manually solved the problem.

I don't know if this was a local or remote issue.